# How to select ID in only 1 criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, where-in

In the dataset shown, I am looking to isolate or show the ID that is only in workbaskets a,b or c but not in d,e or f.  I would expect the ID of 111222 to fit that criteria.  I have tried this SQL with no luck.  Any suggestions?

```
select id
from table
where workbasket in ('a','b','c') and workbasket not in ('d','e','f')

Workbasket  ID
a           111222
a           123456
b           987654 
c           112333
d           123456 
e           987654
f           112333
```

Comment: Adding "solved" to the topic is not particularly useful nor how SO works. You should mark the answer as such.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id
from table
where workbasket in ('a','b','c')

EXCEPT

select id
from table
where workbasket in ('d','e','f')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use NOT EXISTS subquery

```
select id
from table t1
where workbasket in ('a','b','c') 
and NOT EXISTS 
(
 select *
 from table t2
 where t1.id = t2.id
 AND t2.workbasket in ('d','e','f') 
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
WITH CTE(Workbasket, ID) AS
(
   SELECT 'A',123456 UNION ALL
   SELECT 'A',111222 UNION ALL
   SELECT 'B',987654 UNION ALL
   SELECT 'C',112333 UNION ALL
   SELECT 'D',123456 UNION ALL
   SELECT 'E',987654 UNION ALL
   SELECT 'F',112333
)
SELECT C.ID
FROM CTE AS C
GROUP BY C.ID
HAVING MAX(C.Workbasket) IN('A','B','C')
```

Comment: I did this, downvoted for no explanation and heavy modification of original query; Nafis' solution is much cleaner and less hardcoded without an explanation provided.

Comment: @MDev20, Nasif's answer is alright too. But generally I assume GROUP BY to perform better than EXCEPT. (However. I'm not a SQL Server guy, so I don't know if that's the case here too.) Anyway, I just leave correct answers without an explanation, I save my downvotes to incorrect answers.

Comment: Wouldn't this be an invalid answer if more rows were inserted? It's unmaintainable beyond a single-use query IMO.

Comment: @MDev20, that's a good point. You should ask OP what the expected result is if someone later inserts (z, 111222).